# How to set rows of reflected array of a custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, reflection

how can i set the first and second row of my Array By reflection , i have 
set my values to my custom objects, but i cant assign it to the array , because the first and second rows are null

```
var reflectedArray= Array.CreateInstance(classNameType, 2);

Object itemOfArrayTemp = Activator.CreateInstance(classNameType);

reflectedArray[0] = myValue1;

reflectedArray[1] = myValue2;
```

the error is :

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Array'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the SetValue method on the reflectedArray

```
reflectedArray.SetValue(value1,0);
reflectedArray.SetValue(value2, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `[]`, you can use the [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk3bwkb0(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
reflectedArray.SetValue(myValue1, 0);
reflectedArray.SetValue(myValue2, 1);
```

Please note that the value is the first parameter, the index the second.